# MVC Controller Veracode error 915. Bind Include complex data type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding, veracode

I am doing an Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC Application.

I am having and error 915 from Veracode in the Method in the Controller. I read some [article](https://www.veracode.com/security/dotnet/cwe-915)

And I put this in practice like this

```
[HttpPost("Search")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([Bind(include: "SSN,EmployeeNumber,LastName,FirstName")] SearchModel searchModel)
```

where `SearchModel` class is

```
public class SearchModel
    {
        [StringLength(11)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string SSN { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [MaxLength(20)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [MaxLength(20)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

It works fine.

The problem I have now, I do not know how to use it when the class I get as parameter it contains other clasess as property

```
[HttpPost("Update")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(UpdateModel model)
{}
```

where `UpdateModel` is

```
public class UpdateModel
    {
        public Participant? ParticipantInfo { get; set; }
        public List<SpecificFieldsModel>? ParticipantSpecificFields { get; set; }
        public List<Affiliate>? Divisions { get; set; }
        public List<Employee>? EmployeeClasses { get; set; }
        public List<StateModel>? States { get; set; }
        public List<DependentNewModel>? Dependents { get; set; }
    }
```

Some of that classes like Divisions, EmployeeClasses, States will be null.. I use it to fill the Page, but I do not need them when Submit. I need to exclude that classes.

How can I use Bind Include for `UpdateModel` class to include only the classes I need?

Thanks